# Regrouping Entries in Numpy Array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array.  The best way I can describe it is an array of arrays.  I have N arrays that are all the same size (L x M).  What I need to do is obtain the value for each (L,M) combination and assemble these combinations into a list of N values.

Example:

I have 400 arrays that are 8 x 8.  I need to obtain the value of (2,5) for all 400 arrays and put them in a list.

I have looked into numpy.dsplit() and numpy.array_split(), but either I'm not applying them correctly or they aren't what I'm needing.

Can anyone advise me?  And, no, at this point, I don't have any code to show beyond obtaining the original array, and as that is research data, I'm not comfortable posting it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic indexing.

If, for instance, `myArray.shape` is `(400, 8, 8)`, you'd pull those values out with:

```
myArray[:, 2, 5]
```

(the colon means "everything in this dimension")

Comment: Thank you!  You must excuse such a basic question... I'm very new to using Python, so I didn't realize my task could be handled so simply.  This is precisely what I needed.  :)

Comment: @user3421870 I didn't include the word "basic" to be disparaging. But there's also "fancy" indexing and slices and whatnot. Just trying to help you hone in on the correct search terms.

Comment: Oh, no, I didn't think you did.  I have come across "basic" in many contexts as I've been trying to learn, and I didn't take it to be disparaging.  I just don't want other readers/posters to see this and think, "Good God, why is she even asking that??"  I'm a newbie!  But thank you, I'm definitely accepting your response!  :)